# SQL queries priority of Math

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As you can see on picture I'm working on Employee Salary payment project.

But I had a problem about TOTAL. I would like to do : `(HOURS*perHOUR)+(SALES/100)*COMMISSION = TOTAL`

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.TBL_NEWDAY.NAME,
       SUM(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWDAY.HOURS AS FLOAT)) AS HOURS,
       SUM(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWDAY.SALES AS FLOAT)) AS SALES,
       AVG(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWEMPLOYEE.NEPHOUR AS FLOAT)) AS PHOUR,
       AVG(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWEMPLOYEE.NECOMISSION AS FLOAT)) AS COMISSION, 
       SUM(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWDAY.HOURS AS FLOAT)) * 
       SUM(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWEMPLOYEE.NEPHOUR AS FLOAT)) + 
       SUM(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWDAY.SALES AS FLOAT)) / 100 * 
       SUM(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWEMPLOYEE.NECOMISSION AS FLOAT)) AS TOTAL
FROM dbo.TBL_NEWDAY INNER JOIN
     dbo.TBL_NEWEMPLOYEE
     ON dbo.TBL_NEWDAY.NAME = dbo.TBL_NEWEMPLOYEE.NENAME
GROUP BY dbo.TBL_NEWDAY.NAME
```

I did everything pretty much just priority of math calculating is wrong that is why my Total is wrong.

Comment: Tag the DBMS product which are you using (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server ... etc.). "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: _"I had a problem"_ So why didn't you tell us what it is? _"my Total is wrong"_ How? What should it be? What do you get instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are listing PHOUR and COMISSION column as AVG, but using as SUM at the total.
Your total column formula should be like this.

```
 ( SUM(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWDAY.HOURS AS FLOAT)) *
     AVG(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWEMPLOYEE.NEPHOUR AS FLOAT)) ) 
 + ( SUM(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWDAY.SALES AS FLOAT)) / 100 ) 
 * AVG(CAST(dbo.TBL_NEWEMPLOYEE.NECOMISSION AS FLOAT)) AS TOTAL
```